# Kinetic energy from Euler and continuity equations vs work done by buoyancy force

Tags: fluid-dynamics, work

I have a feeling there's something elementary to it, but I can't seem to understand why I get these answers. I am interested in a stationary 1D inviscid fluid described by the Euler and anelastic continuity equations:
\begin{equation}
\rho u\frac{du}{dz}=-\frac{dP}{dz}-\rho g=-\Delta\rho g
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\frac{d(\rho u)}{dz}=0.
\end{equation}
Where gravity is downwards, doesn't vary appreciable and the fluid is considered to be always in pressure equilibrium with the surroundings.
I can rewrite the continuity equation as
\begin{equation}
-u^2\frac{d\rho}{dz}=\rho u\frac{du}{dz}
\end{equation}
and then the term on the left of the Euler equation as
\begin{equation}
\rho u\frac{du}{dz}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{d(\rho u^2)}{dz}-\frac{u^2}{2}\frac{d\rho}{dz}=\frac{d(\rho u^2)}{dz}.
\end{equation}
Thus I can write the difference of the fluid's kinetic energy as:
\begin{equation}
\Delta K=-\frac{g}{2}\int\Delta\rho dz=\frac{W_b}{2},
\end{equation}
which is half of the work done by the buoyancy force. Why this factor of two? Did I get anything wrong?

EDIT:
Maybe for 1D inviscid fluids buoyancy is not a conservative force? But where does the dissipation goes? If $\Delta\rho =\frac{d\rho}{dT}\Delta T$, surely it can't heat further the fluid. But then, the energy conservation equation is missing. It ought to link $\Delta T$ and $u$, so the system is overspecified. Then we need to relax the pressure equilibrium constraint, which probably doesn't really makes sense for a ID fluid anyway, so that heat is dissipated by lowering the fluid's pressure?